# Can I add extra widgets to a child widget in UMG-UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, ui-design, inheritance

I have a widget base class and I would like to reuse (logic and wigdets as well) it.
I created an empty widget and set the parent class to the base class I would like to inherit from in the class settings.
Works fine.   [image]
But when I am trying to add any widget on top the pre-existing ones just disappear, they get overridden by the children, I guess.   [image]

I found [this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/unreal-engine/feedback-for-epic/72844-feature-request-umg-widget-inheritance?100961-FEATURE-REQUEST-UMG-widget-inheritance=) post for a feature request, but it is quite old.

Just wondering if it is possible to add extra widgets without getting rid of the parent ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an overlay which will allow you to put multiple widgets onto one widget.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: As soon as I put an overlay on the child widget all inherited stuff goes...

Comment: You need to wrap everything with the overlay.  Right click on your top component, choose wrap with a select overlay.

Comment: I'm not able to make it work, even with overlay, adding item into the child hierarchy fully removes the parent's.